# Swift: Search for string in core data model

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm confronted with the following problem in Swift.

I wrote the following function to retrieve all persons in my model with the `name` "David".

```
private func myFetchRequest()
{
    let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    let myRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "RegisterOfPersons")

    myRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", "David")

    do{
        let results = try moc.executeFetchRequest(myRequest)

        for result in results
        {
             print(result)
        }

    } catch let error{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Even though my model contains two entries with the `attribute` name = "David", the line

```
myRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", "David")
```

does not find these entries, because "name" is an optional attribute in my model.
Do I have to search for Optional("David"), meaning something like `myRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", Optional("David"))`?

How can I search for all entries with the name "David" in my model? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure, but having `name` be an optional attribute is not related. Swift optionals are not the same thing as Core Data optional attributes.

Comment: Does the literal syntax `NSPredicate(format: "name = 'David'")` work ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are predicating with `string` so enclose your comparison name with single quote like this

```
myRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = '%@'", "David")
```

Also try with `Contains`

```
myRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[cd] %@", "David")
```

Comment: This will compare with the literal string %@.  From the predicate programming guide "If you use variable substitution using %@ (such as firstName like %@), the quotation marks are added for you automatically."

Comment: @pbasdf I know that but op is using `=` that is the reason suggesting to op to add Single Quote.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
I tried as you suggested. However, it still doesn't work. Maybe I am making a mistake somewhere else?

Comment: Is you property name contains David or exact David, if it is contains than you need to use `CONTAINS[C]` instead of `=`.

Comment: Check my edited answer, and give reply is it working or not?

Comment: Thank you very much NDoc! Thanks to your post I found out that the name in the database contained a spelling miss! Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
         @IBAction func searchbtn(_ sender: Any) {

        
            let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "StudentDetails")
            let searchstring = self.searchbar.text
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "rollno == %@", searchstring!)
            var outputstr = ""
            do
            {
                let result = try context.fetch(request)
                if result.count > 0
                {
                    for oneline in  result
           
                {
                    
                    oneroll = (oneline as AnyObject).value(forKey: "rollno") as! String
                       onename = (oneline as AnyObject).value(forKey: "name") as! String
                  onemarks = (oneline as AnyObject).value(forKey: "mark") as! String
                                           
                /*outputstr += oneroll + ""
                        outputstr += onename + ""
                        outputstr += onemarks + ""*/
                    }
                }
                else {
                    outputstr = " no match found"
                }
                self.searchbar.text = outputstr
                self.bgvhgvhgvyg.text = oneroll
                self.nma_fld.text = onename
                self.mrk_fild.text = onemarks
            }
            catch{
                print("Error")
            }
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).